# google reCaptcha not rendering

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to render google reCaptcha on my site. I went to [google reCaptcha admin](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin), set a label, and added two domains: one is localhost, and another is mydomain.com.

I followed the instructions and added a script tag before the closing head element:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

At the bottom of my form, I added the reCaptcha div:

```
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY"></div>
```

It's been over 30 minutes, and the reCaptcha isn't rendering neither on localhost, nor on mydomain.com. The developers console in the browser doesn't show any errors. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved when I moved the script tag below the reCaptcha div, instead of placing it inside the head tag like google said. But hey, it finally works.